How were English names transliterated into Russian for official documents?
I understand that the preference in Russian is to transcribe rather than transliterate foreign names.  For official documents such as visas, however, it is often important to Cyrillize the name in a reversible manner -- i.e., in such a way that the original spelling can be recovered and matched against other documents in the original language.
I understand that in November 2024, the Russian government adopted a new computer-based system for Cyrillization of foreign names that tries to take into account both the spelling and pronunciation features of the foreign language.  Before this, however, were there any standard transliteration tables in use (similar to the many other systems for transliterating in the other direction), or were names always transcribed according to the best guess of whatever bureaucrat happened to be processing the document?  (If the latter, this surely would have resulted in a lot of incorrect guesses, since no bureaucrat processing, say, a written visa application from someone named "Louis" would know whether to transcribe the name as Луи or Льюис.) Is there perhaps some GOST standard for (reversible) Cyrillization of English names?

Cyrillic is not Latin so it's not customary to add any letters in the words that cannot be pronounced as written. So any attempt to do reversible transliteration will produce completely garbled, unreadable names given the phonetic difficulty of English. That could be done for Italian or Spanish, though

@alamar There are many exceptions to that, as you can read here (see also this) and here (see also this). Probably most notably, letters ⟨b⟩ and ⟨v⟩ in Spanish are pronounced identically. Example for Italian from those articles: ⟨cèlo⟩ and ⟨cielo⟩ are pronounced identically.

I'm not sure there were any rules.
Someone I know once had to fill out an invitation letter for a foreign relative. It's a document required to obtain a Russian tourist visa.
They followed the process outlined on the Russian government portal. Among other things, it says:

Как правильно перевести фамилию и имя иностранца на русский язык?
Используйте текущие правила транслитерации, которые соответствуют нормам Международной организации гражданской авиации (ИКАО). Россия перешла на этот стандарт в 2014 году.
Правила транслитерации
а → a, б → b, в → v, г → g, д → d, е → e, ё → e, ж → zh, з → z, и → i, й → i, к → k, л → l, м → m, н → n, о → o, п → p, р → r, с → s, т → t, у → u, ф → f, х → кh, ц → ts, ч → сh, ш → sh, щ → shch, ы → y, ъ → ie, э → e, ю → iu, я → ia
За правильность перевода на русский язык фамилии и имени приглашаемого иностранца несет ответственность приглашающая сторона

which advices to use the ICAO rules. This advice is really hard to follow, because the ICAO rules only specify how to convert Cyrillic into Latin, which is obvious from the FAQ itself. I'm not sure if this advice is based on any legal requirements.
The FAQ also mentions that "the inviting party is responsible for the correctness of the translation (sic) of the invited alien's first and last names into the Russian language", whatever it might mean.
The person they invited had a French name, and its transliteration looked and sounded horrible. They ended up putting the best phonetic transcription they could come up with on the letter. This transcription eventually ended up on the visa, and their guest had been admitted to Russia without any problems.

ICAO rules, which absolutely should be used in some cases, e.g.  ID documents aren't absolute in some contexts.  I.e. if particular name is translated in a certain way, e.g. author, historical figure or book character, usually the transliteration persists even if it doesn't match modern norms.  There are also anti-examples of that, where poor Dr. Watson was once Уотсон in print, then became Ватсон in movie and other media had matched new variant. Watson the typewriter inventor always was Уотсон. So, one translator of Road of Glory by Heinlein had missed the joke related to that name.

To add to Quassnoi's answer, there is ISO 9 standard. Yes, a single digit, that's one of core documents.
In addition to standards there is history of transliterations. If names in question are quite common they likely have a pre-existing transliteration. Doubly so, if it's a historic or public figure.
In formal context you may need to communicate with other side to ensure the correctness. E.g. if you meant to publish something under that name, to use it to designate copyrights, etc., your work should be vetted.
In fictional context you may go both with standard or historic, or phonetic approach. Here history of preexisting translations or references should be used. If  the name is a reference to soemthing. That's a rare case when names can be translated. If it references some other person or character, the original translit is preferable.

I myself referred to ISO 9 in the comment to a now-deleted answer by another contributor.  But AFAIK ISO 9 is intended for Cyrillic→Latin transliterations, not the other way around.  Did Russia or the USSR ever use it officially for translating from Latin into Cyrillic?

@Psychonaut they pretended that they didn't. Partially it was incorporated in GOST. That's another standard. Russian Cyrillic (not to mistake it with others) prescribed to be phonetical, so it's pronunciation in original language is transliterated.  It always assumed that you can reverse the table otherwise (e.g. how lat-koi8  converter does).
